# Encrypting passwords on POST Django

Tags: python, django, encryption

aside from using SSL, is there any way to encrypt a password in the Django framework on the first POST to the server? For example, if I have a form that accepts a username and password, then send it to another view, aren't the passwords sent to the backend unencrypted? If so, is there a way to encrypt the passwords before transmitting to the backend?

Comment: Django is a server-side application framework. It isn't responsible for transporting the requests from the client to the server. What you are asking for would have to be done by either the client or the transport itself. SSL via the webserver is probably the obvious solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSL is a de facto solution, but if for some reason you can't have it, then you'll find shelter in some javascript libraries that encrypt post data. And there are plenty of them if you search.. But I don't believe that any of them can achieve maximum security.

Comment: Truth. Relying on client-side solutions is not wise. Besides, SSL certs are CHEAP (GoDaddy has them for $12.99/yr!). Just use SSL and worry about more important things.

Comment: If I'm using AWS, should I be worried that the incoming passwords can be seen by other virtual machines?

Comment: cfarm54, I once use http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/ worried about the same, however. hymloth is right, SSL is the way to solve it. You can always use self-signed certificate if you can't buy one