# encrypting data submitted through a form in django

Tags: django, forms, encryption

I have a form in django that stores some info in a database. I want the data submitted through the form to be encrypted when it is submitted (before it goes into the table so that it appears encrypted as it is being sent) and then to be able to decrypt it when retrieving it from the table. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by "appears encrypted as it is being sent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532972/encrypting-passwords-on-post-django/7533960#7533960). Your options include SSL or (worse) some javascript-based encryption.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this solution http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2489/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2489/ for a start.